# "First" versus "before"

Tags: word-choice

Which of the following sentences is more correct or preferable?

> You have to **first** install the PHP filter module.

> You have to install the PHP filter module **before**.

The second sentence seems truncated, to me, as I would expect a sentence similar to "You have to install the PHP filter module before enabling the module you downloaded."

The reason I am asking is that in Italian *first* (as adverb) and *before* are both translated with *prima*. The correct Italian sentence would be the equivalent of the first one.

Comment: The first one is okay; the second is not okay. The first one could also be (a) "First, you have to install the PHP filter module" or (b) "You have to install the PHP filter module first". (a) & (b) are better than the first sentence you suggest.

Comment: The second one does not sound correct.I may be wrong, but AFAIK, before always preceedes another event.

Comment: This is one of those times when it actually isn't ok to end a sentence with a preposition.  The first sentence is correct.  The second sentence works if 'before' is changed to 'beforehand' (not used quite as often these days) or simply use 'first' in its place

Comment: @mcalex Ending a sentence with _before_ is not necessarily wrong: You could say "I have seen him before."

Comment: @kiamlaluno Understood.  Hence '*This* is one of those times...' and nothing about a blanket ban on 'before' itself being the last word in a sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentence #1 is correct. The adverb first is modifying infinitive ‘to install’.

*Before* can also be used as [subordinating conjunction](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000377.htm).

Sentence #2 can be worded differently.

> Before enabling the module you downloaded, you need to install the PHP filter module.

Answer (score 2):

You can use before at the end of a sentence if you use it in answer to a question such as "Do I install A before B?" The answer could be "Before." 
If the question is "Do I install A before or after B" you can say "You have to install A before."

You can also put it at the end of a sentence if you use it in a statement such as "I did it before."

Comment: Which of the sentences I shown is correct/preferable?